# Could images pixels be stored in 1 D array?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I am training a machine learning model which takes the images as a input responsible for classification, I am storing image pixels in array but i found on internet that images could be stored in 2-D array , Below is my code , if it is stored on 1-D format then how it is done in python because at one index only one value takes place then how (124,124) image stored in it ?

```
training_data=[]
def create_training_data():
    for category in Categories:
        path=os.path.join(DataDir,category)
        IMG_SIZE=(124,124)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_arr=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array=cv2.resize(img_arr,(IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array])
```

Answer (score 0):

For image classification it's usually a better idea to consider your images as matrices, because it helps keep local neighborhood and connectivity information in a natural way, without the need to use fully connected layers or RNNs etc. So, I'd recommend that you don't store your training data in a list. Instead, use what all Deep Learning frameworks do: store them in tensors of size `BxCxHxW` where `B` is your batch size, `C` is the number of channels and `H,W` are width/height. For example:

```
#numpy
training_data=np.zeros([B,C,H,W])
#load a single image inside your loop
training_data[i,:,:,]=cv2.imread(...)
```

If you chose a framework like PyTorch or TensorFlow etc, you'll be able to use their own tensor types that can easily transferred to GPU (which is not the case for numpy arrays).